# Node rdkafka consumer stops fetching messages

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Consumer stops fetching after getting following error
`{ Error: Local: Broker transport failure at Error (native) origin: 'local', message: 'broker transport failure', code: -1, errno: -1, stack: 'Error: Local: Broker transport failure\n at Error (native)' }`

All kafka servers are healthy even then I am getting the transport failure .
After this error consumers stops fetching further messages

Comment: Found any solution for this?